# Finding out your Candidate Score

Tags: support, election

As I'm ill-equipped to be a mod, nobody would vote for me, *and other good reasons*, I am not nominating myself for the current (or past) elections. Thank you, hold your applause.

Still, I am intrigued by the **blue boxes** showing the Candidate Score for nominees. I haven't been able to find a way to generate one for myself (possibly another reason I shouldn't be a mod?). There are many moderation and participation badges and I don't know which are the ones counted, etc...

Is there a way to generate one of these short of nominating yourself and then bowing out?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253783/172958

Comment: Thank you. Not sure this merits another *new* question post, but do you know which badges are the "main" ones, like which are the eight moderation badges, etc.? Is there a link for that also?

Comment: @MeatTrademark If you click to the query itself, you can make it out pretty easily.  It tallies up each class of badge by clearly listing them out in the query.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I see it now. I got tripped up with the first string of badges, then the first mod badge being formatted differently from the rest. Thank you. If you'd put this as an answer, I'd pick it (not like you're hurting for rep), because the other answers aren't quite what you did in the comments and you got here first. I'll wait a day or two, then pick someone else if you haven't wasted more time on me. Really, though, thank you. I love having my curiosity sated. (Really don't mean that to sound weird.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Using the standard SEDE query Kevin linked to with our user ids:](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/298418/candidate-score?UserIds=1530814%2C3622940%2C1252759%2C871050%2C572%2C1234256%2C1065190%2C492405%2C616460%2C224988%2C3366929%2C465378%2C229044%2C1380752%2C100297%2C1849664%2C189134%2C542517%2C2371861%2C2581872%2C109702%2C3001736%2C1069068%2C476%2C995926%2C1952862%2C2876565%2C379693%2C1603234)

Your Score: 14  (5 for rep, 3 mod badges, 3 editing badges, 3 participation badges)

My Score: 8 (2 for rep, 1 mod badge, 1 editing badge, 4 participation badges)

Comment: Ooh. I got 40/40. Maybe I should stand for mod?

Comment: I just saw history erased... fascianting.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Ixrec. You got a participation badge I don't have. Is it for for KNOW IT ALL?!?!!! :P Really, though, thank you.

Comment: how do I use this to find my score?

Comment: @user13267 You put your user id into the "UserIds" box at the bottom.

Comment: how do I get my user id? Entering user13267 gave me an error and entering just 13267 showed the score for someone else

Comment: @user13267 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98771/what-is-my-user-id

Comment: @Ixrec Thanks...

Comment: @user13267 Apparently 13267 = 13716.

Answer (score 5):

[Here](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/298418/candidate-score?UserIds=3267,3804,1027,2765) is the Query run for the current site  mods.

```
User Link        Total CappedRep BadgeCount ModBadges EditingBadges ParticipationBadges 
---------------- ----- --------- ---------- --------- ------------- ------------------- 
Kevin            36    20        16         5         5             6                   
AncientSwordRage 35    20        15         5         4             6                   
Keen             34    20        14         4         4             6                   
Thaddeus         33    20        13         4         5             4
```

Comment: None of the current site mods have all of the Candidate Score badges? Is that what you're saying? That seems ... weird. Still, I see how that could happen. But still, weird. A couple nominees have more than any of them. Like John Lurie's music label, it's Strange and Beautiful.

Comment: @MeatTrademark Mods can't earn the Deputy or Marshall badges (if they meet the criteria while they're a mod, it won't be awarded until they step down), so if they didn't have them before becoming a mod then there's a hard upper limit. I imagine Reviewer and Steward would also be more difficult for mods to earn, since they only count actions done in the queues. It's not quite as strange as all that